xclip does not create target TIMESTAMP
if I copy some string to the clipboard:
echo -n 'sometext' | xclip -selection c

then
xclip -selection clipboard -o -t TARGETS

the result I get is
TARGETS 
UTF8_STRING

however if I copy 'sometext' the normal way, i.e. copy+c from some text editor then
xclip -selection clipboard -o -t TARGETS

displays
TIMESTAMP
TARGETS
MULTIPLE
SAVE_TARGETS
UTF8_STRING
COMPOUND_TEXT
TEXT
STRING
text/plain;charset=utf-8
text/plain

why is this?

It depends on which target atoms "some text editor" actually makes available as an X selection when you copy something "the normal way". As an aside, use xclip -r instead of echo -n.

so I guess xclip only makes available the target UTF8_STRING
